# Implementing Retry button for Retrofit error on LiveData observable

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-paging

learner here and I'm trying to add a retry button for whenever there is an error in Retrofit `Callback#onFailure` method.

*Somewhat following the Android Architecture Guide*, I'm able to call, persist the data and show it on RecyclerView. Here is a general flow of what I've done so far:

On `PagedList.BoundaryCallback` I'm getting the response and saving it. Here I've also created a LiveData of `NetworkState`, which I'm observing within `MainActivity` through `ViewModel` class.

```
@Override
public void onZeroItemsLoaded() {
    if (isFetchNeeded())
        mClient.fetchFirstNetworkCall().enqueue(getRetrofitCallback());
}

@Override
public void onItemAtEndLoaded(@NonNull Item itemAtEnd) {
    if (mNextPageToken != null)
        mClient.fetchNextNetworkCall(mNextPageToken).enqueue(getRetrofitCallback());
}
```

```
@Override
public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<BloggerApi> call, @NonNull Response<BloggerApi> response) {

    mObservableNetwork.setValue(NetworkState.LOADING);

    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        mExecutors.diskIO().execute(() -> {
            insertItemsToDb(responseBody.getItems());

            mObservableNetwork.postValue(NetworkState.SUCCESS);
        });
    } else {
        String error = response.errorBody() == null ? "Unknown Error" : String.valueOf(response.errorBody());
        mObservableNetwork.setValue(NetworkState.error(error));
    }
}

@Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<BloggerApi> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
    mObservableNetwork.setValue(NetworkState.error(t.getMessage()));
}
```

And then on UI:

```
mViewModel.getNetworkState().observe(this, networkState -> {
    if (networkState.getStatus() == Status.ERROR) {
        retryButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            // todo: Implement what to do
        });
    }
});
```

I'm lost here and don't know how implement a Retry button to make the last call if for some reason I get an error. Can you please help me out about what the Retry button should actually do to get the callback?

Thank you.

P.S. I'm new to Java, and as of now Kotlin is out of my league so couldn't figured out how Google sample projects implementing the retry method, and, also my sample project is on [GitHub/DemoBlogApp](https://github.com/RajarshiMandal/DemoBlogApp) for any reference. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself long time back but was waiting for an opinion. While I didn't got any, thought of posting an answer to *myself* so that others may find it useful.

Retrofit has `clone()` method which can be super useful for situations for failures. So basically, make an interface:

```
public interface RetryCallback<T> {
    void getCall(Call<T> call, ApiCallback<T> callback);
}
```

On Retrofit failure:

```
class Repository {

    RetryCallback<Api> retryCallback;
    //...

    new Callback<Api>() {
        // other Callback methods

        public void onFailure(Call<Api> call, Throwable t) {
            retryCallback.getCall(call, this);
        }
    }

    public void setRetryCallback(RetryCallback<Api> retryCallback) {
        this.retryCallback = retryCallback;
    } 
}
```

On MainActivity:

```
//...
// Using lambda instead of initializing with new operator
viewModel.setRetryCallback((call, callback) ->
    call.clone().enqueue(callback);
);
```

Comment: I am trying this approach but whenever my API fails, it goes into OnFailure method where retryCallback is null and my application crashes. Can you help me